# Tool to produce HTML documentation with WYSIWYG or WYSIYM editor?

Tags: html, text-editors

One of my colleagues has been tasked with producing documentation for three different products.  The documentation needs to be in HTML, and if not properly compliant, at least close enough to display on IE, FF, & Chrome.  The plan is to deploy it on a web server, and also install it along with one of the products.

My initial reaction is to recommend the following tech. stack:

- LyX
- LaTeX2HTML
- GNU Make

I've used the above stack on a number of projects before now, and also to produce my personal website.

However, this place is predominantly a Microsoft shop, and the colleague in question has a preference for WYSIWYG over [WYSIWYM](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5770).  He's also not a developer so suggestions like 'to change the footer just edit this Perl script' won't sit comfortably.

Can someone recommend an alternative tool or tech. stack (either Free or proprietary) that would allow a non-developer to build nicely structured, well indexed HTML documentation using MS Windows?

I'm quite happy for people to plug their own products :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [friend & colleague](http://www.arminsadeghi.com/) of mine has recommended [RoboHelp](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp/).

Answer (score 0):

https://codverter.com/src/webeditor - you can write HTML, CSS and JavaScript code Securely (everything is interpreted on the client machine) while viewing web page results in a split screen mode.  
great for scraps, drafts and quick starts.

(Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers).
[image]